Can std::chrono's time_point silently overflow?
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  constexpr std::chrono::duration<float> kLastWarningMsgDuration{ 10 };

  // default time point (zero)
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point lastWarningMsgTime1;
  // minimum time point (some negative value)
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point lastWarningMsgTime2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::min();
  // current time point
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point lastWarningMsgTime3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  bool result1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastWarningMsgTime1 >= kLastWarningMsgDuration;
  bool result2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastWarningMsgTime2 >= kLastWarningMsgDuration;
  bool result3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastWarningMsgTime3 >= kLastWarningMsgDuration;

  std::cout << result1 << std::endl;  // true, more than 10 seconds
  std::cout << result2 << std::endl;  // false ???
  std::cout << result3 << std::endl;  // false, less than 10 seconds
}

I didn't dive too deep into this but I guess the problem is that the second result overflows over what the poor 32-bit float can hold. I could live with this discovery however there's one thing which got stuck in my head and it is this presentantion's bold statement:

If you make a reasonable change that doesn't involve explicit type
conversion syntax (and it compiles), you can have confidence that you
have not introduced a bug.

Well, this confidence has been quite shaken for me now. Did I misunderstand what time_point::min() does or that statement is not entirely true?

You cannot overflow float with an int to float conversion. You can only lose precision. What's happening is the integer subtraction in now() - lastWarningMsgTime2 overflows. The value in lastWarningMsgTime2 is set to 64 bit signed integer minimum. Subtracting that from any value > -1 will overflow.

BTW UB sanitizer detects this issue: https://godbolt.org/z/vMTxa4Eeo

It's not float that's overflowing (that'd be a very large number), std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - lastWarningMsgTime2 is taking some presumably smallish positive integer and subtracting the maximum sized negative integer. Assuming std::chrono::steady_clock uses int64_t you're essentially doing:
int64_t lastWarningMsgTime2 = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();
int64_t now = 12345;
int64_t diff = now - lastWarningMsgTime2;

This obviously overflows, as int64_t is signed this is undefined behaviour (gcc gives a large negative number as the result https://godbolt.org/z/rPYM6oj75).
Most std::chrono implementations use signed 64-bit values in their durations, even if those durations are nanoseconds that gives you a range of nearly 600 years, therefore in normal usage the statement you've quoted would be correct. In normal usage subtracting two timestamps wouldn't overflow but yes there is no checking for overflows in std::chrono.
There are obviously still pitfalls, subtracting time_point::min() is one of those pitfalls but I can't see a reason why you'd normally want to do that.

The reason why I did it was quite naive: I was looking for some "impossible" value so my 10s (or whatever) limit would succeed in the init phase. It didn't occur to me to use the default constructed value at first.

@MiroKropacek all clocks have an epoch. It's only meaningful to talk about calculations that fit within one epoch of the clock.

@MiroKropacek in the case of steady_clock its probably quite safe to use 0 as your sentinel value as its typically the boot time of your computer so all real values will be positive and non-zero (though check what your implementation does before making that assumption)

@MiroKropacek If you want to keep using min() as the initial value, change your comparison to the safer lastWarningMsgTime + duration < now(). However, when the duration is float, that will lose precision, so you should make a duration_cast<std::chrono::steady_clock::duration> first

If you have, or want to use, some sort of "safe int" class that asserts or throws on overflow, one can use that with chrono to find bugs like this.  You can just create your own duration and time_point family that works with steady_clock, but makes noise when it overflows.
